# shell string with file replacement using sed -r

Tags: sed, sh

```
sed -i  $'/<!--Change here-->/ {r ${TEST_DIRECTORY}/check.html\n d}' "${TEST_DIRECTORY}"/result.html
```

Above sed with file read not taking actual value of `${TEST_DIRECTORY}`

```
{r ${TEST_DIRECTORY}/check.html\n d}
```

but it works with actual value

```
{r dir1/dir2/check.html\n d}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside single quotes are not expanded by your Bourne shell. Use double quotes instead:

```
sed -i  $'/<!--Change here-->/ {r '"${TEST_DIRECTORY}"$'/check.html\n d}' "${TEST_DIRECTORY}"/result.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need double quote like below:-

```
sed -i  $"/<!--Change here-->/ {r ${TEST_DIRECTORY}/check.html\n d}' ${TEST_DIRECTORY}/result.html"
```